# Getting error at starting mayan "No module named 'sqlalchemy'"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mayanedms

I try to use the Mayan-EDMS for my project. In my Django project, I have Postgres and Redis containers so I made changes in Mayan-EDMS docker-compose.yml file to work with my Postgres and Redis. Following is the Mayan `docker-compose.yaml` code:

```
services:
  app:
    environment: &mayan_env
      MAYAN_CELERY_BROKER_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
      MAYAN_CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://username:Password123@xx.xx.xx.xx/celery
      MAYAN_DATABASES: "{'default':{'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql','NAME':'mayan','PASSWORD':'Password123','USER':'username','HOST':'xx.xx.xx.xx'}}"
      MAYAN_DOCKER_WAIT: "xx.xx.xx.xx:5432 redis:6379"
    image: mayanedms/mayanedms:3
    networks:
      - abc_network
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    volumes:
      - ${MAYAN_APP_VOLUME:-app}:/var/lib/mayan
      - /opt/staging_files:/staging_fi
      - /opt/watch_folder:/watch_folder
```

And when I do docker-compose up app I am getting an error `CommandError: Error during signal_pre_upgrade signal: No module named 'sqlalchemy', <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>`. full log as follow:

```
abc@abc-3567:~/Desktop/mayan-edms$ docker-compose up app
Starting mayanedms_app_1 ... 
Starting mayanedms_app_1 ... done
Attaching to mayanedms_app_1
app_1  | mayan: starting entrypoint.sh
app_1  | Waiting for xx.xx.xx.xx:5432
app_1  | Waiting for redis:6379
app_1  | mayan: update_uid_gid()
app_1  | usermod: no changes
app_1  | mayan: os_package_installs()
app_1  | mayan: pip_installs()
app_1  | mayan: performupgrade()
app_1  | Operations to perform:
app_1  |   Apply all migrations: acls, actstream, admin, appearance, auth, authtoken, autoadmin, cabinets, checkouts, common, contenttypes, converter, django_celery_beat, django_gpg, document_comments, document_indexing, document_parsing, document_signatures, document_states, documents, dynamic_search, events, file_caching, file_metadata, linking, lock_manager, logging, mailer, mayan_statistics, metadata, motd, ocr, permissions, quotas, sessions, sites, sources, storage, tags, user_management, web_links
app_1  | Running migrations:
app_1  |   No migrations to apply.
app_1  | CommandError: Error during signal_pre_upgrade signal: No module named 'sqlalchemy', <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>
mayanedms_app_1 exited with code 1
```